# attaching skype contact Microsoft Bot framework

Tags: botframework, skypedeveloper

My question is about how do i attach a skype contact to my chat bot, here in the code below i am able to attach an outlook email contact that opens an outlook window when i click on it, but now i want to open the skype window of the person i am contacting.

```
case "finance":
                await context.PostAsync($"For {ig} related queries write to [Finance Mailbox](mailto:bpml.coe@gmail.com;%20karmit.dhawan@gmail.com?subject=Dhg:%20Need%20further%20assistance)");
```

Answer (score 0):

See skype URI syntax here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype-sdk/skypeuris/skypeuriapireference

So your link should look like `skype:targetUserName`. There are also parameters like `call` or `chat` that can be added to force the interaction type.

Here you could do:

```
case "finance":
                await context.PostAsync($"For {ig} related queries write to [Finance Skype](skype:targetUserName?chat&amp;topic=yourTopic)");
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I forgot to mention i wanted to connect skype for business not Skype.